# Ajax: Load page content to div with select box

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I'm trying to load page content into a div via Ajax when a select option is selected

eg. I have a select box with 2 options the values are test.HTML and test1.HTML and under that I have a div and want the content from test.HTML and test1.HTML to load in the div when the select box changes... Via Ajax 
any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, that can be rather simple:

```
$("#mySelect").change(function(){
  $("#myDiv").load( $(this).val() );
});
```

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>test.html</option>
  <option>test1.html</option>
</select>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: I'm giving him the benefit of the doubt :)

Comment: One more thing, when the page loads it should load the selected option (eg the 3rd option is sel on p load) content

Comment: You can cause it to auto-fire by calling the change method immediately after: `$("#mySelect").change(function(){...}).change();`

Comment: thanks for the reply.. can you please give me a exact code for the on page load eg. load mypage.html when the page loads,
thanks