# Load in div based on choice in selectbox

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have an  box in Page1 with some different alternatives and below this a div where I want to load in content (different divs) from an external page (Page2) based on choosen alternative.

Page1

```
<select id="choose_alternative">
<option> Books </option>
<option> Paper </option>
</select>
```

Page2

```
<div id="Book_div">Content</div>
<div id="Paper_div">Content</div>
```

I found [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294843/ajax-load-page-content-to-div-with-select-box) and tried figure out how to use the code and ended up with this:

```
$("#choose_alternative").change(function(){
  $("#show_alternative").load( $(Page2.html #Book_div).val() );
  $("#show_alternative").load( $(Page2.html #Paper_div).val() );
});
```

Does anybody know what I have done wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: what is  `$("#show_alternative")` ??

Comment: @AkbarAli - I think its safe to assume thats the described `div` in `and below this a div where I want to load in content`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, what you want to do is according to the selection load the div. check the code below.

```
$("#choose_alternative").change(function(){

  var choose_alternative  = $("#choose_alternative option:selected").text();

  if(choose_alternative == 'Books'){
     $("#show_alternative").load('Page2.html #Book_div');
  }
  else if(choose_alternative == 'Paper'){
     $("#show_alternative").load('Page2.html #Paper_div');
  }

});
```

else you can just load the content right away

```
$("#choose_alternative").change(function(){
  $("#show_alternative").load("Page2.html #Book_div");
  $("#show_alternative").load("Page2.html #Paper_div");
});
```

[Read more](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Oh snap, you beat me by a few seconds. +1

Comment: and i think u missed "." there.. :)

Comment: Is there anything I must edit in the select box except from its ID? Do the options have to have value or h refs etc? It dont work.

Comment: that depends on the requirement. above code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the relevant part of the documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments

It says to do it like this:

```
$("#choose_alternative").change(function(){
  $("#show_alternative").load("Page2.html #Book_div");
  $("#show_alternative").load("Page2.html #Paper_div");
});
```

Comment: Is there anything I must edit in the select box except from its ID? Do the options have to have value or h refs etc? It dont work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I dont get it to work so something is wrong. Its strange becuse there is other similar scripts on the same page that works great.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function (){    
    $('#choose_alternative').change(function(){
        $show_alternative = $('#show_alternative');
        var selectedElement = $('#choose_alternative :selected');

        switch($(selectedElement).val())
        {
             case " Books ":
                  $show_alternative.load('Page2.html #Book_div');
                  break;
             case " Paper ":
                  $show_alternative.load('Page2.html #Paper_div');
                  break;
             default:
                  $show_alternative.html('No option selected.');
                  break;
        }
    }
}
```

Never forget the `$(document).ready( function(){...})` part; it is what renders your code so it can be triggered.